# Android Dynamic TabView Using JSON Configuration file

Tags: java, android, json, android-layout, android-intent

I Have very specific requirement for this android app, Where I get JSON file from server Like this:

```
[
{"st":"f","t":"PDF","tbico":"107-widescreen.png","f":"PG033%20-%20Blue%20on%20Black.pdf"},
{"t":"Call","tbico":"BG092.png","dialNumBtn":"1231231234","st":"dialNumBtn"},
{"t":"Facebook Photos","tbico":"113navigation.png","fbPgID":"zoo"}
]
```

In pre-built iOS version of this app, Layout will look something like [**this link**](http://cl.ly/image/1Q461Q262t0Y) using above JSON , And I have a task to use this JSON and display it similar way in android (Using TabView) for Example [**this link**](http://cl.ly/image/2n1o0r072d06) 
My problem is: How can i create different Tabs and Fragments Activity that will  adjust it self according to above json (e.g: In case if there is one more object in above JSON, than show one more Tab in Layout)?

This did not help me: [**link**](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/lateral.html), I have parse json and stuff, I need help with How to displaying UI element

Answer (score 1):

You need some serious JSON library here, for instance [Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind).

Create your base class (warn: pseudo code, adapt) so that you have, say:

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public abstract class MyBaseClass
{
    @JsonProperty("t")
    protected String title;
    @JsonProperty("tbico")
    protected final String iconName;

    // etc
}
```

Then extend `MyBaseClass` so as to create an object for each tab type.

Deserialize it using:

```
// customize as needed, see javadoc
final ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
final List<MyBaseClass> l = mapper.readValue(theJson, 
    new TypeReference<List<MyBaseClass>>() {});
```

Either this, or walk the JSON (using JsonNode which is fantastic for that) and create your tabs one by one.

Comment: I'm using gson for parsing JSON, But i dont understand how can i place Tab and Fragments according to JSON. I need logic to place UI using JSON